# What is the correct expression?

Tags: expressions

I am trying not to laugh.  Can I say,"I am trying to keep my laughter away?"

Comment: What are you trying to change in *I am trying not to laugh*? (Keeping laughter *away* isn't idiomatic; *down* or *suppressed* may be, depending on what you're trying to achieve.)

Answer (score 2):

You might consider saying instead, ***keep a straight face***, as in

*I can never play jokes on people because I can't keep a straight face.*

> keep a straight face
>
> Don't show one's feelings, especially refrain from laughing. [Late 1800s]
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/keep+a+straight+face)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common/generalized usage is,  "I am trying to suppress my laughter."  This happened to me recently in yoga class when I kept falling over during a difficult pose and because I was ruining everyone else's "OM" moment by being such a clutz "I could barely keep myself laughing". In that situation I would also say "I could hardly keep myself from cracking up."

Often laughter is triggered by an internal and difficul to suppress response from within.  The opposite can be said for sorrow or tears:  "Trying to keep my sadness away" or "trying to keep my tears at bay" is more common usage of "away" or "at bay" regarding the expression of emotion.